# Netsuite: Is there a way to remove the Save & Print button, only retain the Save button

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

As per question, is there a way to only retain Save button and disable the Save & Print button through code? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## In the UI

1. At the top right of the Item Fulfilment page, click on the link labelled "**Customize**".
2. On the menu that pops up, click "**Customize Form**"
3. Click on the **Actions** subtab
4. Find the buttons you want to disable, and untick the "Show" checkbox.

## Via a Workflow

You can remove form buttons using "[Remove Button Action](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N2740901.html)" in a Workflow.

## Via SuiteScript

You can use a User Event before load script to remove buttons. In SS1.0 this would be `form.removeButton(buttonid)`, or `N/ui/serverWidget/Form.removeButton()` in SS2.0. There is a list of the Button IDs for standard Netsuite buttons [in the documentation](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_N3265696.html).

Comment: Sharp and accurate. Thank you so much for your input. Appreciated a lot.